# Bad performance of a Graph Algorithm

Tags: javascript, performance, graph

I implemented a solution for the problem below, but its performance is not good.
I know I can find the solution online, I'm trying to understand what is causing the bad performance in `my code`

Problem:
You have an undirected, connected graph of \$n\$ nodes labeled from \$0\$ to \$n - 1\$. You are given an array graph where \$graph[i]\$ is a list of all the nodes connected with node \$i\$ by an edge.

Return the length of the shortest path that visits every node. You may start and stop at any node, you may revisit nodes multiple times, and you may reuse edges.

Test Cases:

```
Input: graph = [[1,2,3],[0],[0],[0]]
Output: 4
Explanation: One possible path is [1,0,2,0,3]
```

```
Input: graph = [[1],[0,2,4],[1,3,4],[2],[1,2]]
Output: 4
Explanation: One possible path is [0,1,4,2,3]
```

My code:

```
var shortestPathLength = function(graph) {
    const totalNodes = graph.length;
    let output = Infinity;
    
    const smallestPathFromNode = (node) => {
        let count = Infinity;
        let queue = [];
        queue.push([node, new Set(), 0]);
        while(queue.length > 0) {
            const [curNode, visited, moves] = queue.shift();
            if(visited.size === totalNodes) {
                count = Math.min(count, moves)
                continue;
            }
            if(moves > count || moves > output)
                continue;
            const nextNodes = graph[curNode];
            for(const nextN of nextNodes) {
                const newVisited = new Set(visited);
                newVisited.add(curNode)
                queue.push([nextN,newVisited,moves+1]);
            }
        }
        return count-1;
    }
    
    for(let i=0; i<graph.length; i++) {
        output = Math.min(output, smallestPathFromNode(i))
    }
    
    return output === Infinity ? 0: output;
};
```

Test case with a bad performance (takes too long to execute):

```
[[2,3],[7],[0,6],[0,4,7],[3,8],[7],[2],[5,3,1],[4]]
```

Comment: Many posts on this site might be about graph algorithms and a larger number might be about bad performance. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Any idea of how the title should be? My issue is exactly "Bad performance on a graph algorithm problem"

Comment: What kind of graph algorithm? "Shortest path that visits every node" narrows it down dramatically, for starters.

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 the body of the post explains that the performance is not good. A title that would _simply state the task accomplished by the code_ might be something like _Determining shortest path to visit every node in a graph_. If the problem came from an off-site challenge then you could add the [tag:programming-challenge] tag and include a link in the body of the post.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thank you for checking the title. Any idea on how to improve the code?

Comment: What do you mean by takes too long? Running the code with the test case executed almost instantly. What you could do to optimize this is have an ordered queue (heap) by number of nodes visited first.